# Generate array of bin sizes in Excel

Tags: excel, frequency

The [FREQUENCY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840100.aspx) function in Microsoft Excel is useful for generating histograms. The first parameter is an array of data values (E.g. A1:A100). The second one is an array of bin sizes. I want to *generate* this array from three parameters:

- Minimum data value: MIN(A1:A100)
- Maximum data value: MAX(A1:A100)
- Bin size: constant

That is, a formula/function should return the list of wanted values instead of manually putting them in cells.

E.g. Consider a minimum value of 10, a maximum value of 100 and a bin size of 20. This would yield an array of the follow bin sizes: 10, 30, 50, 70, 90

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that array generated by a formula try this

`=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&CEILING((MAX(A1:A100)-MIN(A1:A100))/B1,1)))-1)*B1+MIN(A1:A100)`

where B1 is your bin size constant, e.g. within the FREQUENCY function that would be

`=FREQUENCY(A1:A100,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&CEILING((MAX(A1:A100)-MIN(A1:A100))/B1,1)))-1)*B1+MIN(A1:A100))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER