# Clamp/filter data set used for Excel chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 2010, consider a set of data values ranging from M to N. These values are used to display a chart. Now, let's say I want to skip values that match certain criteria. How would I do that?

E.g. Column $A contains values ranging from 0 to 100, but I want to skip values below the value of $E$1 and values above the value of $E$2. Hence, something like "Get all values from column A, remove all values below $E$1 and above $E$2 and then plot a chart of the remaining values!"...

I'm trying to improve the solution marked as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599645/419776).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are referring to the name *Data* for your chart values and you want to restrict values to a range between $E$1 and $E$2. You could define another name *DataRange* to refer to the formula:

`=IF(Data>$E$1,IF(Data<$E$2,Data))`

and update your chart values to refer to *DataRange*.

In the linked example it looks like you are plotting the equivalent of `=FREQUENCY(Data,Bins)`, so substituting *Data* for *DataRange* should give a histogram of restricted values. Another approach you might consider for this purpose is a PivotChart which allows for grouping and filtering of data.

Comment: This is a good start, but I'm not sure the `IF` formula is sufficient. The chart keeps showing two `#REF!` columns... Does the `IF` produce some non-number values?

Comment: The `IF` formula will return *FALSE* for values outside the range, it was intended to be used inside the `FREQUENCY` formula. Can you post a simplified version of the data you are plotting?

Comment: I pretty much followed the linked example, and changed _all_ occurrences of `data_vals` to `data_range` which is set to `=IF(data_vals>=Blad1!$E$2;IF(data_vals<=Blad1!$E$3;data_vals))`. Your formula seems right, but the chart doesn't like it...

Comment: Hmm. It's the labels that are erroneous. It doesn't like the `data_range` inside the formula for `bin_array` and `bin_labels`. However, I'm not sure I get the right result if I use the unfiltered data for these two variables.

Comment: Charting with names can throw up unexpected problems sometimes. Pressing Alt+F11 and using the immediate window may help e.g. enter `names.add "data","=IF({1,2,3}>1,2,1)"` then select the chart series and enter `selection.values="Sheet1!data"` to update the chart. Values in names can be viewed in the watch window e.g. by entering `[data]`.