# Excel Histogram - Distribution Line

Tags: vba, excel, histogram

I want to make a histogram in excel which is easy using data analytics toolbox. If I wanna make it automatic in `vba` I can use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580062/histogram-using-excel-frequency-function) to get the bins automatically and then set the reference ranges.

Problem arises when I want to have the smoothed distribution line. If I change the chart type to scatterplot smooth line, it will connect the columns height to each other which will be like the blue line in this picture:

[image: Histogram]

But what I really want is something like the purple line (i.e. a normal distribution overlaid on top of the histogram). This is not be desired if the data is skewed or generally have a different distribution. Is there anyway to make this overlay automatic in reference to distribution of the data? *(Something like what R does)* Preferably using macro, but any input would be great.

Comment: I don't think that this is a programming related question but more a mathematics/statistics related question, therefore this might be the wrong place. Maybe [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) is something for you

Answer (score 1):

I added a Trendline to my chart (in red) and then formatted the Trendline as "Polynomial" and it achieved an effect similar to what you have. [image: Polynomial Trendline]

Here's some code to achieve this programatically:

```
Sub AddPolynomialTrendline()
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim chrt_obj As ChartObject
    Dim trend As Trendline

    For Each chrt_obj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    If chrt_obj.Name = "Chart1" Then
        With chrt_obj.Chart
            'the number after xlPolynomial is the order, which can be from 2 to 6
            Set trend = .SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add(xlPolynomial, 6)
        End With
    End If
    Next chrt_obj
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!